# EF Core: Get Authenticated username in Shadow Properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, entity-framework-core

As a part of logging who entered/updated the data I am adding 4 common fields (Created By, Created Date, Modified By, Modified Date) in all entities. For this, I am using shadow properties feature suggested in multiple forums including https://dotnetcore.gaprogman.com/2017/01/26/entity-framework-core-shadow-properties/

My question is **how do I get information about authenticated user ?**. If it was a controller I could access ApplicationUserManager but in this case the shadow properties are in

**AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext**  class.

This is a asp.net core 2 web API project.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get the current user's name using `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`. You can access the `HttpContext` using `IHttpContextAccessor`. This interface should already be registered in the service collection. Otherwise, you can register it:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
         options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    // ...
}
```

Then, you can use this interface from the `DbContext`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        : base(options)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;
        if(httpContext != null)
        {
            var authenticatedUserName = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;

            // If it returns null, even when the user was authenticated, you may try to get the value of a specific claim 
            var authenticatedUserId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value
            // var authenticatedUserId = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("sub").Value

            // TODO use name to set the shadow property value like in the following post: https://www.meziantou.net/2017/07/03/entity-framework-core-generate-tracking-columns
        }

        return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am getting NULL even after registering IHttpContextAccessor in the service collection. Any suggestion....

Comment: Which property is null: `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext` or `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`?

Comment: _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name is null

Comment: You should call `SaveChanges` only after the user is authenticated in the aspnet pipeline. You can check if the user is authenticated using `_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

Comment: Yes, I am already doing that. Even if the user is authenticated, the Name is null.....

Comment: I used _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("sub").Value to get authenticatedUserId

Comment: This code is kind of dangerous because there's no null gaurds on HttpContext. If you're not within a request pipeline (migrations, seeding, usage of the context in a console app, etc), this will blow up with NullReferenceExceptions accessing anything off HttpContext.