# C# and Entity Framework Core v7.0.2 code-first - DbContext database provider error during migration Initialization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I want to initialize my database with Entity Framework Core 7.0.2 using a code-first strategy.

But when I launch this command:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --project PreventionCyber.DAL --startup-project PreventionCyber.Web
```

I get this error :

> System.InvalidOperationException: No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the 'DbContext.OnConfiguring' method or by using 'AddDbContext' on the application service provider. If 'AddDbContext' is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

PCDbContext.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using PreventionCyber.DAL.Common;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PreventionCyber.DAL.Context
{
    public class PCDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public PCDbContext()
        {
        }

        public PCDbContext(DbContextOptions<PCDbContext> options): base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            foreach (var entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                // Renommage clé primaire
                entity.GetProperty("Id")
                    ?.SetColumnName($"{entity.ClrType.Name}Id");
            }
        }

        public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            OnBeforeSaving();
            return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
        }

        private void OnBeforeSaving()   
        {
            var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries();

            foreach (var entry in entries)
            {
                if (entry.Entity is BaseEntity trackable)
                {
                    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    var user = GetCurrentUser();

                    switch (entry.State)
                    {
                        case EntityState.Modified:
                            trackable.ModifieLe = now;
                            trackable.ModifiePar = user;
                            break;

                        case EntityState.Added:
                            trackable.CreeLe = now;
                            trackable.CreePar = user;
                            trackable.ModifieLe = now;
                            trackable.ModifiePar = user;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private string GetCurrentUser()
        {
            return "UserName"; // TODO implement your own logic

            // If you are using ASP.NET Core, you should look at this answer on StackOverflow
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/48554738/2996339
        }
    }
}
```

Program.cs

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using PreventionCyber.DAL.Context;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// AddAsync services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContext, PCDbContext>(options
    => options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStrings:PreventionCyber")));

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.Run();
```

I don't understand the error because I've already defined a constructor using `DbContextOptions<TContext>` and I added the `DbContext` to the `builder.Services` too in `Program.cs`.

Can anyone find the error? Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you remove the empty constructor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error suggested you may need to add the OnConfiguring override method to the PCDbContext class.

````
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
            options.UseSqlServer(<yourConnectionString>);
        }
    ```
````

Comment: I added the method as you suggested and it worked ! Thanks !